# How to bind ItemsControl of Labels to an ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have an ItemsControl who has an ItemsSource that is an ObservableCollection. The DataTemplate contains Label controls. My goal is to set the Content property of each of these Labels to the elements in the ObservableCollection but right now, the Content is entirely blank for each of the Label.

It is worth noting that this ItemsControl is nested within another, parent ItemsControl, but let me show:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource={Binding StudentCollection}">
 <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate> 
  <DataTemplate>
   <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <ColumnDefinition Width="90"/>
     <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    // This is the ItemsControl that is not working properly with the Labels


   <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding StudentActivitiesCollection}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
      <Label Content="{Binding Sport, UpdatedSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
     </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
   </ItemsControl>
  </Grid>
 </DataTemplate>
 </ItemsControl.Template>
</ItemsControl>
```

This is my StudentsActivities class:

```
public class StudentActivities : INotifyPropertyChanged

  private string sport;
  public string Sport
  {
    get
    {
     return this.sport;
    }
    set
    {
     this.sport = value;
     OnPropertyChanged("Sport");
    }
   }
  }
}
```

And my working View Model:

```
 private ObservableCollection<StudentActivities> studentActivitiesCollection;
 public ObservableCollection<StudentActivities> StudentActivitiesCollection
 {
  get
  {
   if (studentActivitiesCollection == null)
      studentActivitiesCollection = new ObservableCollection<StudentActivities>();
    return studentActivitiesCollection;
   }
  }
```

This is the method I am using to populate my ObservableCollection in my ViewModel:

```
private void PopulateStudentActivitiesCollection(ObservableCollection<Student> Students)
{
 foreach (Student s in Students)
 {
   StudentActivitiesCollection.Add(new StudentActivities () { Sport = StudentSport });
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: I updated my post, sorry.

Comment: Please post your classes. What is StudentCollection?

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource={StudentCollection}">
```

to

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource={Binding StudentCollection}">
```

and

```
<Label Content="{Binding Sport, UpdatedSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

to

```
<Label Content="{Binding Sport}"/>
```

The last change is not needed but not necessary either.

Comment: I added some code for reference, I had the binding for StudentCollection, I just forgot to copy it over. I updated my post.